# Python Nested Dict how to independently update value

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dict with similar values:

```
{'Gryffindor': {'Arithmancy': 0.0, 'Astronomy': 0.0, 'Herbology': 0.0, 'Defense Against the Dark Arts': 0.0} 
'Hufflepuff': {'Arithmancy': 0.0, 'Astronomy': 0.0, 'Herbology': 0.0, 'Defense Against the Dark Arts': 0.0}}
```

I want to update single value. The probleme is when i update dict['Gryffindor']['Arithmancy'] it will also update dict['Hufflepuff']['Arithmancy'].
I don't realy know why.

I use this:

```
thetas["Gryffindor"]["Arithmancy"] = 12
```

and i've go this result :

```
{'Gryffindor': {'Arithmancy': 12, 'Astronomy': 0.0, 'Herbology': 0.0, 'Defense Against the Dark Arts': 0.0} 
'Hufflepuff': {'Arithmancy': 12, 'Astronomy': 0.0, 'Herbology': 0.0, 'Defense Against the Dark Arts': 0.0}}
```

Any ideas ?

EDIT :

Thanks for your reply this is the loop i use :

```
thetas =  {'Gryffindor': {'Arithmancy': 0.0, 'Astronomy': 0.0, 'Herbology': 0.0, 'Defense Against the Dark Arts': 0.0} 
'Hufflepuff': {'Arithmancy': 0.0, 'Astronomy': 0.0, 'Herbology': 0.0, 'Defense Against the Dark Arts': 0.0}}

for _, house in thetas.items():                 
    for k, v in house.items():
        house[k] = 0.1
     print(thetas)
     exit()
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing a bit more of your code? It's hard to trace back the error with a single line. Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce your error... what you expect to happen is the behavior in Python. It looks like you're missing a comma between the keys in the dictionary (before 'Hufflepuff'). My guess is you've set the other value elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is down to how you've assigned values to keys in `dict`. Apparently you have something like the following situation:

```
class_grades = {"Arithmancy": 0.0, "Astronomy": 0.0, ...}
thetas = {"Gryffindor": class_grades, "Hufflepuff": class_grades, ...}
```

However exactly you've arrived there, when you access / modify `thetas["Gryffindor"]`, it's the very same object / instance as the one referred to from: `thetas["Hufflepuff"]`. I.e. it's down to how you've initially populated your `dict`s. You can validate the assumption by asking for `id()` of each nested `dict`:

```
print([id(i) for i in thetas.values()])
```

Unique instances have unique ids. Same objects / instance report the same id.

If you wanted to have initial `dict` of values and then populate each "house", you could instantiate a new dict (with the same values)... in this case (no further nesting), simply calling `dict()` would be enough, e.g.:

```
class_grades = {"Arithmancy": 0.0, "Astronomy": 0.0, ...}
thetas = {"Gryffindor": dict(class_grades),
          "Hufflepuff": dict(class_grades), ...}
```